# Express JS routers are not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I just started to study nodejs and express, and was trying to make a simple router. In the beginning it worked, if I remember correctly, but since I reopened the project it hasn't worked anymore.

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var route = express.Router();

route.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send('Something');
})

app.get('/post',route);

app.listen(3000);
```

When I make a `GET to 127.0.0.1:3000/post` I expect "Something" in my response body, instead I get the default node 404.

The problem is that the path is not "cut", in fact it works if I use `route.get('/post',...`;
from what I have seen in many examples, and from the documentation itself, when a router is invoked, the path is "cut", am I wrong?

For now I have tried to reinstall express, thanks in advance for your answers. I searched around and couldn't find any other similar problems.

Comment: Usually, one would use `app.use()` to hook in a router such as `app.use('/post', route)`.  Not sure if that makes a difference here or not.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm going to do some tests.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks, that was exactly the problem! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jfriend00 pointed out to me in the comments, the mistake is to use `.METHOD()` to invoke the route, rather than `.use()` .

Answer (score 0):

It's because you didn't register the **middleware** (use is a way to register middleware) and you don't need two endpoints ('/'). your code runs perfectly now:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var route = express.Router();

route.get('/post',(req,res)=>{
    res.send('Something');
})

app.use(route);

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Sure, the server is fully functional, if I make any request directly to **app**, it works perfectly. The problem occurs only with routers, which behave exactly like **app**.